# How can I get my data to be displayed along a line with python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-visualization, frequency-analysis, python-3.6

I am writing a program that counts how many times each letter is typed to help me with frequency analasis. My program works, but it always outputs part of my answers along a curvy line. Example output:

```
Length of message: 591 characters
A  11 1%
B  27 4%
C  37 6%
D  2 0%
E  2 0%
F  5 0%
G  17 2%
H  8 1%
I  9 1%
J  49 8%
L  7 1%
M  44 7%
N  20 3%
P  42 7%
Q  6 1%
R  36 6%
S  1 0%
U  6 1%
V  22 3%
W  13 2%
X  56 9%
Y  11 1%
```

I am using the following code:

```
text = input()
symbols = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
letters = collections.Counter(text.upper())
length = len(text)
print('Length of message: {} characters'.format(length))
for letter, times in sorted(letters.items()):
    if letter not in symbols:
        continue
    percent = str(int((times / length) * 100)) + '%'
    print(letter, times, percent)
```

I am trying to get it displayed something like this:

```
A 11 1%
B 27 3%
C 37 6%
D 2  0%
E 2  0%
F 5  0%
G 17 2%
H 8  1%
I 9  1%
J 49 8%
L 7  1%
M 44 7%
N 20 3%
P 42 7%
Q 6  1%
R 36 6%
S 1  0%
U 6  1%
V 22 3%
W 13 2%
X 56 9%
Y 11 1%
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

To pad with a number of spaces:

```
print(('{:<2}{:<3}{:<3}').format(letter, times, percent))
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you want to display it. One of the ways would be to add tabs in your print statement.

For example:

```
print(letter,"\t", times,"\t", percent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged Python 3.6, use the new [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

```
import collections

text = input()
symbols = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
letters = collections.Counter(text.upper())
length = len(text)
print(f'Length of message: {length} characters')
for letter, times in sorted(letters.items()):
    if letter not in symbols:
        continue
    percent = times / length
    print(f'{letter} {times:2} {percent:5.1%}')
```

There is no need to compute the percent string manually.  Just compute the float value `percent = times / length` and use the proper formatting in the f-string.

`{percent:5.1%}` means: insert "percent" variable here in a field of width 5, with one place after the decimal.  `%` is a format specifier that multiplies the number by 100 and adds a percent sign.  `{letter}` is inserted with no special formatting, and `{times:2}` makes a 2-wide field that is right-justified for numbers by default.

Output of input "abbbbbbbbbbccc":

> ```
> Length of message: 14 characters
> A  1  7.1%
> B 10 71.4%
> C  3 21.4%
> ```

See also:

- [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)
- [PEP 498 -- Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)